# can't override inline style with ! important property?

Tags: html, css, overriding

I have a div which defined as follow:

```
<div style="background-color: rgb(217, 240, 211) ! important; color: rgb(0, 102, 2) ! important;" class="div_box">... ...
</div>
```

since the div is currently using the inline style (which I hate this!) I need to override the background color as well as the color.

I have tried:

```
.div_box[style] {
background-color: rgb(216, 219, 215) ! important; 
color: rgb(94, 94, 94) ! important;
}
```

but doesn't work. Also tried .div_box { ... } and still not working.

So my question is, how am I override the above div style without manually changing the inline style?

Comment: !important should be written with no space and sticked to last value :) color: rgb(94, 94, 94)!important;

Comment: you cannot override inline !important styles.

Comment: An article to read about [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) in CSS :)

Comment: specificity doesn't help in this situation.

Comment: @G-Cyr you saved my life

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inline CSS overides CSS stylesheets. Both of them are marked !important, in your case so you can't use this css trick to change the div color.

Short answer, you can't do what you want. It,s possible only if inline CSS would not have been marked as !important.

Comment: True. A workaround for the example case could be to use an inset box-shadow with a large spread. 

`.div_box { box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 300px rgb(216, 219, 215); }`

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/UkpnZ/3/

Since you can't remove the inline style, as pointed out (that I skipped over), if you can use Jquery, you can use this:

```
$('.div_box').css('background-color', '');
$('.div_box').css('color', '');
```

to strip the background-color and color attribute from the inline style where .div box appears. The only added issue here, is that it will strip this everywhere the class is called.

Using this method, you no longer need `!important` in your stylesheet either.

Comment: `So my question is, how can I override the above div style without manually changing the inline style?` - Read please

Comment: I know that I can always use the javascript/jquery to take out/change those styling, it's just I prefer using the css to override. Too bad this can't be done as the inline was marked as !important